# Same Media Query Min and Max Width with Different Layouts

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm having a problem with media queries in terms of layout. Example, I have:

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

    .this-is-a-box {
      font-size: 20px;
      padding-left: 5%;
      padding-right: 5%;
    }

}
```

But when the layout becomes smaller than 920px in width, I will need the value to achieve:

```
.this-is-a-box {
   font-size: 15px;
   padding-left: 1%;
   padding-right: 2%;
}
```

Hope someone can help with this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Soooo why not use two media queries to specify that boundary?

```
/* Small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 919px) {

    .this-is-a-box {
       font-size: 15px;
       padding-left: 1%;
       padding-right: 2%;
    }

}
/* Larger screens */
@media screen and (min-width: 920px) {

    .this-is-a-box {
      font-size: 20px;
      padding-left: 5%;
      padding-right: 5%;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Golez. Did not work for me but the idea did work and i tried nesting the media query. Although I do't know why the nesting doesn't work in my other media queries except for the former one I did.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to experiment on GolezTrol's suggestion and instead did it like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 919px) {

css here

}


@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

css here

   @media screen and (min-width: 920px) {

      css here
   }

}
```

Never knew that was possible. But any drawbacks on this?

Thanks!